# What does the toggle tool handle position do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I was looking at Unity Editor's Interface, I suddenly found a small icon[image: Here]. Then I hovered on it, and the text of toggle tool handle position appeared. I googled it and found the Unity Documentation website, it said:
( this is the website => https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html )
"Use the dropdown menu to switch between Pivot and Center.

Pivot positions the Gizmo at the actual pivot point of the GameObject, as defined by the Transform component.
Center positions the Gizmo at a center position based on the selected GameObjects."

What are the actual pivot point of the GameObject and the center position based on the selected GameObjects? I HAVE TRIED TO ROTATE AND POSITION THE GAME OBJECT BUT IT DOESN'T WORK :'(

Comment: Try it and see. Not all objects have the pivot in the middle.

Comment: for example? which objects don't have the pivot in the middle

Comment: The pivot is where ever it was designed to be. So no one will necessarily be able to give you an exact example.

Comment: A door makes for an easy example.  If the pivot of a door was in the center, when you rotate it, it will spin (think revolving door).  With the pivot on the one side of the door (like a hinge irl), it will swing.  Of course you can make the door with the pivot anywhere, so to say "All doors have their pivot off to the side" would be an incorrect blanket statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pivot of an object is defined in the 3D file being used. It is often called the origin or transform. For example, in Blender or 3DS Max you could have the pivot set to vector 0, 0, 0, or you could have it set to one of the vertices positions. Imagine
a cube 1mx1mx1m at position 0,0,0 - you could have the origin at 0,0,0, or you could use the top, right, forward vertice position, which would be (1, 1, 1).

The principal is the same when you select multiple objects in a scene; you can either have the pivot position for an individual object, or you can have an averaged position of all the objects selected. For example you have one object at (1, 0, 0) and one at (2,  0, 0) you can either have the pivot at (1,0,0) or (1.5, 0, 0).

The most use for this is when you want to rotate. Do you want to rotate a group of objects around a particular object, or do you want to rotate around their shared centre?

Comment: oh, so this is mostly used when I want to rotate a group of objects?

Comment: Yes, though it's also useful for positioning, especially with snap settings on. As you work more with 3D this will become obvious over time.